# Is it possible to avoid busy-waiting in a spinner?

Tags: ros, roscpp, spinning, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've read the [Callbacks and Spinning](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) page, and have written the following spinner:

```
void SteeringCtrlr::callCallbacks()
{
  static const double timeout = 0.01;
  while (node_->ok())
    cb_queue_.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
}
```

If there are no callbacks in the queue, the "while" loop will busy-wait, using a lot of CPU time. I could not find a CallbackQueue equivalent of select(). Is it possible to implement such a thing? For example, is it possible to call select() on the sockets over which topic messages and service calls are received (if sockets are used for that purpose). I can reduce the frequency with which callAvailable() is called by creating a ros::Rate object and calling sleep() on it, but I'd rather avoid busy waiting at all if possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9688/is-it-possible-to-avoid-busy-waiting-in-a-spinner?/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2011-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I understand the documentation, your loop above does not cause busy-waiting and should not at all consume a lot of CPU time. callAvailable will block and wait for an event to arrive until timeout expires. Internally, callAvailable performs a timed_wait on a condition variable that gets triggered whenever a new callback becomes available.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-09-22**:
Still, 0.01 seconds timeout is not very much. The CPU usage would decrease even more with a longer wait, if you can afford the additional lag on node termination.

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on 2011-04-13**:
Thank you. I did not understand the distinction between a callback that is "ready" and one that is "available," thinking that the terms were synonymous. Also, I was confused by the phrase "wait for a callback to be available" in the documentation. I'm accustomed to GUI callback systems, in which a callback is a function, and therefore is always available. I now understand that what is meant is "wait for a callback-triggering event, such as a message from a topic, to be available." I hope this clarification helps someone.